# How i open my application as soon as I receive notification of that app

Tags: android, performance

I would like to know how do I make an application that is running in the background open automatically when I have some event.

Comment: which notification, is it come from your app or others?

Comment: Whats is your code were you are receiving the notification? please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Android Manifest allows you to set up filters that act much like a listener to start an Activity. startActivity(intent); allows you to fire an event that starts the Activity. Not quite sure of specific way to do this in your code unless you share the code if packages are different you may need pending intent to get around permissions. Are you lanching Service or activity?